# c# calling native dll - struct marshaling

Tags: c#, pinvoke, marshalling, dllimport

I'm trying to call this c dll function

```
long foo (long l2, long l2, char *c, MYSTRUCT *mystruct);
```

that requires this struct:

```
typedef struct {
    bool b;
    short s;
    double d1;
    double d2;
    double d3;
} MYSTRUCT;
```

Now, this should be very simple. I did like this:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct MYCSSTRUCT
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I1)]
    public bool b;
    public Int16 s;
    public double d1;
    public double d2;
    public double d3;
}
```

And called the function like this:

```
    [DllImport("my.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, SetLastError = false)]
    public static extern Int32 foo(Int32 l1, Int32 l2, string c, ref MYCSSTRUCT mycsstruct);
```

but, in the end, the dll receives properly all the values but d1, d2 and d3. And I don't get where and why there is an error. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: your c function does not appear to be `__stdcall` if you call it from C# with `CallingConvention.StdCall` the runtime won't find it, and even if it did you'd corrupt the stack.

Comment: Well, actually the full function definition is:
__declspec(dllimport) long __stdcall foo (long l2, long l2, char *c, MYSTRUCT *mystruct);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, but I finally found out myself.

I was missing that the block of instructions where the c struc lies, is defined with

```
#pragma pack (2)
```

so, I just modified my c# struct definition as follows:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 2)]
public struct MYCSSTRUCT
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I1)]
    public bool b;
    public Int16 s;
    public double d1;
    public double d2;
    public double d3;
}
```

Game done.

Answer (score 1):

Your `bool` field might be causing the error. The problem is in `bool` size - it is not the same in c# and c++.
Read [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaredpar/archive/2008/10/14/pinvoke-and-bool-or-should-i-say-bool.aspx) article about that.

Try using `int` field instead of boolean.

Comment: win32 `BOOL` is an `int`, but this isn't c++ code where the `bool` would be 1 byte. It's C according to the OP, in which case it's implementation defined in `stdbool.h`